# Toast message not shown on poor internet speed

Tags: java, android, android-toast

I am facing some weird issue. I am sign in user in my app but before that i check for internet connection. For that i am Toasting message saying wait while we are verifying your details. This all works fine but when network is poor it does not toast any message and it takes time to sign in.

This is my code

```
   @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_google_signin:
            showToast(getString(R.string.signing_in_wait_text));   // This message is not shown on poor network
            overLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (AppUtil.isNetAvailable(this)) {
                Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            } else {
                showToast(getString(R.string.internet_connection_down_or_poor));
                overLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            break;
    }
}

 private void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

overlay is my loading view to notify that he is signing in app. And below is my isNetAvailable() method

```
public static boolean isNetAvailable(final Context context) {

    boolean isInternetWorking = false;
    try {
        isInternetWorking = (boolean) new InternetConnectionTest(context).execute().get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        return isInternetWorking;
    }
}
```

InternetConnectionTest is asyntask which check for internet. This is how i am checking for internet

```
    private static class InternetConnectionTest extends AsyncTask {
    Context context;

    InternetConnectionTest(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

        Boolean success = false;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://google.com");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            connection.connect();
            success = connection.getResponseCode() == 200;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        finally {
            return success;
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine when internet is speed is good. And when my device is not connected with internet it shows message for internet is down. But problem comes when my internet speed is very low. It takes some time to login but does not show toast message. Please help

Comment: The connection speed shouldn't stop the toast showing. Are you sure it hits that line? Put a breakpoint or a Log.d there to make sure.

Comment: @billynomates even i am wondering why this is happening. I used log and Log.d ... Toast message line is executing but no toast appear on screen

Comment: You said it yourself that checking for connection is an async task, yet in your case it's not, because you stop running thread to wait for it to finish. If Toast is also some task, then stopping current thread from running might mean that you will not be able to see the toast appear, as it would flash very quickly.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Thanks man.... I removed .get() from Async Task and did all required changes and it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

when the net is slow, it means that the connection is more than timeout you set,
so you can just add you your toast method in the catch block of your doInBackground mothod, I think it will work!